# Mechatronics Engineering is about Precision or intelligence?

Tags: robotics

i have Question that Mechatronics Engineering is all about Precision or intelligence , from precision i mean that to follow pattern precisely with precise time and from intelligence i mean making intelligent decisions based on input using image processing etc. 
for example i google these Mechatronics keyword and i got these images

a) auto industry robotic arms manufacturing cars : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NIJe.jpg
so my Question is these auto industry robotic arms just follow precise pattern or they have cameras in them and they assemble or cut parts of cars based on what they see in camera added to them ( image processing ).
if no camera then it mean if car assembly is bit off from its position they could make mistake and could mess up things ?

Comment: So have you checked how these arms work? What components do they use?

Comment: @SolarMike ya i know basic robotic arms just your stepper/servo motors and mechanical assembly to move around it specific pattern , but am not sure about industrial grade robotics arms that how they work that they use camera to recognize items or just follow static pattern loaded in their controller.

Comment: What about CNC lathes etc? what control do they use?

Comment: ya CNC is also static they follow just xy coordinates sent to them throw gcode.

Comment: @user889030 Industrial quality CNC machines aren't that simple. For example they automatically measure wear on the cutting tools, and adjust the programmed coordinates to compensate for it.

Comment: On a typical modern car assembly line like your picture, *every car coming down the line is different* because the buyer gets to choose from a long list of options to customize exactly what they want to buy. You can't deal with that with a "dumb" robot arm.

Comment: @alephzero but then again neither is a CNC machine, each part can be different ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern robots are precise. given the same inputs they produce the same outputs. A signal turns on and the arm moves to a position. Every time the same signal turns on, the robot arm moves back to the same position, often with in 10's of microns.

The intelligence is to some degree illusionary. A computer program running on the robot controller is simply executing a program responding to various inputs such as single sensors detecting the presence of part or values from a vision camera providing an X and Y coordinate of part center in its field of view. Based on the inputs in accordance with program code it produces outputs, including moving the robot arm to various locations.

For some applications the programming is fairly simplistic, it other cases it maybe vary complicated. Besides the application code there will be code to actually control robot functions such as motion planing, handling emergency stop signals, and controlling and monitoring its own power supplies.

Mechatroincs combines knowledge of mechanical systems such as the robot arms transmission systems, electrical / electronic such as the electrical motors and electronic circuits for things like inputs and outputs, with the controls and software. it is a large skill set to master, but the career field is rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither, one or both. Think of Mechatronics as just modern machine building. The key idea is that there is no single reason for mechatronical machines.
The aim can be any of, but not limited to:

- Faster
- Cheaper
- Better
- With less parts
- more flexibility
- Higher precision

Now since your main method is to include control systems into all this intelligence follows.

Most robots are static. They just dumbly do things like a CNC. But since they are programmable, you end up bolting methods to aim, or pick things that dont come with a superior control. Having a digital intrface enables you to do that. And it will happen over time that you add more inteligence. Its a side effect, and then a goal.